# Support for C-Functions in Future Version of C++ / CString vs. LPCTSTR / Binary Datatypes

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc, migration

We have to migrate an MFC-Project (Multibyte Code/ANSI) to Unicode/Windows 7. In that project many C-Functions like _tcschr, _tcsncpy, _stprintf, _tcslen... are used.

LPCTSTR is often used instead of CString. char* is used to make binary Operations.

I think there are many Pitfalls with LPCTSTR and Unicode(example: _tcslen).So I want to replace LPCTSTR with CString/ const CString. New Function should use the String-Methods of CString.

char should be replaced by TCHAR, because CString is based on TCHAR.
I don't care about char and binary Operations in Future. The Length of 8 bit seems to stall by 8 bit, but what is with the Encodings, ..?

So my questions are:

- How long is it planned to support this old C-Funktions in Future (VS 2013, VS 2015,...)?
- Is there a tested Library that is based on CString to replace this old C-Functions (less effort)?
- What datatype should I use for binary Operations for Future Support?
- Is there a reason not to Replace LPCTSTR through CString (with cast operator to LPCTSTR)?

Comment: If you are going Unicode then don't use the `T` versions, use instead the `W` versions.

Comment: if you are doing this BIG work here, then I would suggest to not use CString, but use the strings from the std namespace for cross platform compatibility

Comment: For binary you can use the `BYTE`type (which is ascually `unsigned char`.

Comment: Replacing `LPCTSTR` by `CString` can be easy in certain parts of your program, and pain full in others. It really depends on a lot of factors.

Comment: Replacing `LPCTSTR` with `CString` buys you nothing, when you want to drop MBCS support. You'd want to use `CStringW` instead. Of course, you could opt to use standard C++ strings (`std::wstring`) and have one less dependency to worry about. Those C functions you name are the `TCHAR` versions of standard CRT functionality. They'll stay until noone uses the Windows API anymore. This isn't going to happen any time soon.

Comment: Thank You for the Answers! 
I agrree with You! I should use string when I write a new Project. I would use C++ and C#.
But I have to migrate Code with as less effort as it is possible. 
It is a MFC-Project produced by many Developers in many Years. It's a less C++, but most Code it's C-like (incl. Exceptions)!

So it's too much affort to cast the data in the diverse data Structures like LPCTSTR, LPCSTR, char*, ...
In MFC "string" made trouble with Unicode. Some chars like arabic Letters did show "?". "CString" do not shredder this Chars. 
What did I wrong with "string" and MFC?

Comment: I hope that the TCHAR Macro and CString will work as long as possible. And I hope that the used C-Function will work too.
CString will work with MCBS and Unicode.  
In MSDN I read that I should use the _T Macro and use the generic Functions (_fgettc, _vsntprintf, ...);- if I want to migrate in Future to Unicode. 

So why I should use CStringW (W-Versions)?

Comment: I think one Point is clear:

 In Future I would use BYTE for (binary) Byte-Arrays and "char*" is History.

Comment: You appear to be making consistently wrong decisions. There is nothing gained from replacing the standard C++ type `unsigned int` with a platform-specific type `BYTE`. If you think there are problems with `LPCTSTR` and `_tcslen`, you will have **identical** problems with `CString` and its `GetLength` member. Please read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) before making another decision.

Comment: I have to migrate an MFC-Project from Visual Studio 6 to Visual Studio 12 with less effort.  It is an nearly 17 Years old MFC-Project. It works with 90% Macros and nearly 90% C-Code. It should not run on any unix Platform. It only should run 100% on Windows 7, - awful!

Comment: The Macros are Fact and I can't blow them away. I would use string and all other nice platform Independent structures if it where a new Project and C# or Java for the View...
But that Dreams at the Moment!
Fact is LPCSTR, LPCTSTR and the other old C-Functions. 
I know how Unicode works and "CString/CStringW" seems to work correctly with all Forms of Encodings. "string" at the moment have Problems with not ANSI chars like arabic and chinese chars under Unicode and MFC. I don't really know why. 
And how should I solve the Migration?

Comment: `CString` and `CStringW` work with precisely 2 character encodings: MBCS (codepage) and UTF-16. Nothing else. If you need UTF-32 or (more commonly) UTF-8, you'll have to manually convert, using [WideCharToMultiByte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130.aspx). Neither `CString` nor `std::string` will be of any help. You also appear to be missing one significant detail: Internationalization takes **significantly** more effort than replacing MBCS strings with Unicode strings ([Introduction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318661.aspx)).